# Visual Studio 2019 always search in all files (including the hidden files)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How can you search in Visual Studio (2019) only in the included (project) files?

I think it is a few months ago that this behavior changed. If I search for somthing I hit ctrl-F and type the search word. Clicking "Find All" would list all files that are also included in the projects/solution that has a hit... Now if I do the same I got more hits; because it is also including files that are in directories that are not included by the project/solution (like a DIST folder).

I did some research and it looks like the extended search (find in files / ctrl-shift-F) has an option called "Include external items". Looks like that option should do what it is now doing; however this option is switched off...
What am i missing? has there been an update that changed this behavior; and should i change another setting if i want the old behavior? Are there other people that confirm this behavior change?

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.11.2
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your "Find in Files" dialog settings? Also, what exact version of VS are you using?

Comment: I added the information in the origional question... I am not sure how this "File types" combo has been filled (default filter?). But use an empty filter does the same... I could add !*\dist\* there; that would fix this specific issue; but i want a more general solution were i don't need to exclude folders but just don't search in hidden files.

Comment: Does disabling _Include miscellaneous files_ help?

Comment: it does not. If i understood correctly this will search in files that you have opened but are not part of the solution. However the issue is that it is searching in files that are not open, are not part of the solution, but are located in the solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

in VS2019

Tools -> Options - > Project and Solutions -> VC++ Project Settings

then in right panel

add to "Extension to hide" all extensions in which VS are searching:  for example ".obj"
then OK

after refresh project in Soultion explorer and all files with this extensions will be hide after that
ctrl + F with Find in Project and all will ok